# Scala Exercises: blocked with the `Option` exercise

Tags: scala

[image]

I'm currently revising my scala after a very long hiatus and i just can't get this answer - I've tried every possibly answer under the sun. I know this isn't typical stack overflow content but I have no clue what it is, what is the correct answer for the red underlined text?

Comment: The error message gives you a hint. A String is provided but it expects an `Option`. How can you build up an `Option` from a `String`? Hint: `Some`thing is done in the previous line.

Comment: Also, it would be good to have a relevant title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your comparing `String` vs `Option[String]`...use `Some("I am wrapped in something")`

[Imgur link showing this working for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1zMN.png)

Incase this helps the literal text entered into that checkbox is `Some("I am wrapped in something")`

The second input box contains `None`

Comment: yeah I've already tried that , it returned the error "Evaluation failed : Compilation Error ; ERROR -> ']' expected but '}' found. at [277, "

Comment: can you copy paste screen shot of this error you mentioned in the comment? I can't seem to get a compilation error on that page at that specific line number.

Comment: the thing in quotes in my original comment is the error